# Detecting Edges on Reflective Objects

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

What approach works best for detecting pertinent edges on highly reflective surfaces? Only one salient object is present in each image. Ideally, I would get the edges that connect corners only and filter all others. Under certain lighting conditions, that's exactly what happens, but the light occasionally breaks those edges. Thanks in advance!

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a2ho.jpg)

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: I tried all the classic edge detection methods (Sobel, canny, etc.) along with drawing contours to get a rough outline of the figure for pose estimation

Comment: Reflections destroy all information and introduce fake edges. If you want to reconstruct, your only chance is to use some a priori information such as "there are long, uninterrupted edges".